# RxJs SwitchIfEmpty Custom pipable operator

Tags: typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have created a new RxJs(6) operator switchIfEmpty(other), it switches to `other` when the source is empty.

i'am new in marble tests, i've created some tests for validating my operator, all tests pass except one. i dont know if the bugs comes from the operator or the test !

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export const switchIfEmpty = <T, R>(emptySource: Observable<R>) =>
  (source: Observable<T>) => {
    return new Observable<T | R>(subscriber => {
      let empty = true;
      const subscription = source.subscribe(
        e => {
          empty = false;
          subscriber.next(e);
        },
        error => subscriber.error(error),
        () => {
          if (empty) {
            const innerSub = emptySource.subscribe(
              innerE => subscriber.next(innerE),
              error => subscriber.error(error),
              () => subscriber.complete()
            );
            subscription.add(innerSub);
          } else {
            subscriber.complete();
          }
        }
      );
      return subscription;
    });
  };
```

the test spec:

```
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing';
import { of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { switchIfEmpty } from './switch-empty';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

describe('SWITCH IF EMPTY OPERATOR', () => {

  let scheduler: TestScheduler;

  beforeEach(() => {
    scheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });
  });

  it('switchIfEmpty : source not empty', () => {
    const source = '-x-y-z|';
    const expected = '-x-y-z|';
    scheduler.run(helper => {
      const source$ = scheduler.createColdObservable(source);
      helper.expectObservable(source$.pipe(switchIfEmpty(of(1)))).toBe(expected);
    });
  });

  it('switchIfEmpty : source empty', () => {
    const source = '|';
    const expected = '(1 a|)';
    scheduler.run(helper => {
      const source$ = scheduler.createColdObservable(source);
      helper.expectObservable(source$.pipe(switchIfEmpty(of('1', 'a')))).toBe(expected);
    });
  });

  it('switchIfEmpty : source error', () => {
    const source = '-x#';
    const expected = '-x#';
    scheduler.run(helper => {
      const source$ = scheduler.createColdObservable(source);
      helper.expectObservable(source$.pipe(switchIfEmpty(of(1)))).toBe(expected);
    });
  });

  it('switchIfEmpty : empty source switched to error', () => {
    const source = '|';
    const expected = '#';
    scheduler.run(helper => {
      const source$ = scheduler.createColdObservable(source);
      helper.expectObservable(source$.pipe(switchIfEmpty(throwError('error')))).toBe(expected);
    });
  });

  it('switchIfEmpty : empty source switched to delay', () => {
    const source = '|';
    const expected = '--x|'; // tried '--(x|)' not work
    scheduler.run(helper => {
      const source$ = scheduler.createColdObservable(source);
      const switchedSource = of(1).pipe(delay(20));
      helper.expectObservable(source$.pipe(switchIfEmpty(switchedSource))).toBe(expected, {x: 1});
    });
  });
});
```

only the last one is not working:

```
it('switchIfEmpty : empty source switched to delay', () => {
    const source = '|';
    const expected = '--x|'; // tried '--(x|)' not work
    scheduler.run(helper => {
      const source$ = scheduler.createColdObservable(source);
      const switchedSource = of(1).pipe(delay(20));
      helper.expectObservable(source$.pipe(switchIfEmpty(switchedSource))).toBe(expected, {x: 1});
    });
  });
```

the error message

```
SWITCH IF EMPTY OPERATOR switchIfEmpty : empty source switched to delay FAILED
        Expected $.length = 0 to equal 2.
        Expected $[0] = undefined to equal Object({ frame: 2, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: 1, error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }).
        Expected $[1] = undefined to equal Object({ frame: 3, notification: Notification({ kind: 'C', value: undefined, error: undefined, hasValue: false }) }).
            at TestScheduler.assertDeepEqual (http://localhost:9876/src/switch-empty.spec.ts?:12:22)
            at http://localhost:9876/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/testing/TestScheduler.js?:122:1
            at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
            at TestScheduler.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/testing/TestScheduler.js.TestScheduler.flush (http://localhost:9876/node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/testing/TestScheduler.js?:120:1)
```

Comment: It's not working how?

Comment: i juste updated the post with the error log, thank's @martin

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc/blob/master/source/operators/concatIfEmpty.ts

Comment: i like your implementation

Comment: The problem is at this line `subscription.add(innerSub)`, `subscription` is `undefined`. I used an explicit parent subscription, as suggested by https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-composing-subscriptions-b53ab22f1fd5.  
 In the test i changed the delay to 2 not 20. The `expected` is also wrong, the correct value is `'--(x|)'`

Comment: The link in the comment above is no longer valid. The canonical link for that blog post is: https://ncjamieson.com/composing-subscriptions/